# Linear Algebra Terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, translation-request

I'm trying to translate a linear algebra term from my native tongue to English.

The term refers to a set of $n$ vectors over $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that each $d$ vectors from the set are linearly independent.

The literal translation would be "vectors in general position/status", however I really doubt that that would be the right terminology.

Does anyone know what the right wording for such a set of vectors?

Comment: Why not give the phrase in the original language? Many users here are bilingual.

Comment: what is the native term?

Comment: in my class and text we just refer to it as a subset of a set of linearly independent vectors, (the subset is necessarily lin independent).

Comment: @MSEoris: the emphasis here that any subset of $d$ vectors are linearly independent, which isn't the case with an arbitrary set of $n$ vectors, or even a set of $n$ vectors which have a linearly independent set (as opposed to having every subset).

The native term (in Hebrew) would be "וקטורים ב-$\mathbb{R}^d$" במצב כללי"

Comment: I think "vectors in general position" is fairly standard for this concept.  (I disagree with MSEoris; don't call such vectors linearly independent, because they aren't if $n>d$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass thx for pointing that out!

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree that "in general position" is a well-known phrase. For example, three points in general position means three non-colinear points. For, almost all choices of three points will fail to be colinear. Three points failing to be colinear is a generic property, it is open and dense.

Comment: Is it right to say that vectors in general position are vectors that are drawn from the Origin?

Comment: Vectors in general position seems to be a term more fit for geometry than for linear algebra: $\,d+1\,$ vectors are in general position in $\,\Bbb F^n\,$ if any $\,d\,$ of them isn't contained in the same hyperplane=subspace or affine space of dimension $\,n-1\,$ . I'm israeli and cannot remember now any text in hebrew that talks of vectors in general position **outside** of a geometric setup and, of course, not in general, abstract vector spaces.

Comment: Maybe I am confused with Standard position